# How can I make this tagging system sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tagging

I found this jQuery tagging system mentioned on SO: http://webspirited.com/tagit/?page=tagit and I really like it but I need to be able to drag and drop the tags to sort them.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got jQuery UI included in your project, you should be able to call:

```
$( "#tags" ).tagit().sortable();
```

---

**EDIT**

Line 102

Comment out `self._removeTag();` in tagit.js

```
        this.options.select = function(event, ui) {
            //self._removeTag();
            self._addTag(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
```

---

**EDIT**

Example Revised:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="http://webspirited.com/tagit/css/tagit-simple-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
        body, #demo2
        {
            height:150px;
        }
        #demo2
        {
            background-color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="demo2" name="demo2">
        <li>here</li>
        <li>are</li>
        <li>some</li>
        <li>initial</li>
        <li>tags</li>
    </ul>
    <input id="btnGetItems" type="button" value="GetVals" />
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://webspirited.com/tagit/js/tagit.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];


    $(function(){
        $('#demo2').tagit({tagSource: availableTags}).sortable();
        $('#btnGetItems').click(function(){
            getTags();
        });

    });

    function getTags()
    {
        var string = "Tags\r\n";
        string +="--------\r\n";
        $('#demo2 li.tagit-choice').each(function(){
            var $tmp = $(this).clone();
            $tmp.find('.tagit-close').remove();
            string += $tmp.html()+"\r\n";
        });
        alert(string);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but the autocomplete stops working when I add .sortable() -- it replaces the whole input with the selected tag also the showTags function is not returning the tags sorted so you're solution is only visually sorting them.

Comment: @emurad, see above for the revised example. I think it addresses all your concerns. You'll just need to style it to fit your implementation.

Comment: Great but there's one bug left. When I select an item from the suggestion list it replaces the last tag instead of adding a new one.

Comment: @emurad, Appears to be a bug with the tagit plugin (behaves the same on their website). I'd try to contact the Author/find the user forum. Or you could open another question here. Overall, I feel this is a separate issue.

Comment: Actually, before adding sortable() selecting with the mouse works fine. The problem exists on their website with keyboard selection only.

Comment: @emurad, this is my last edit. Hopefully you'll be able to go from here. Good luck!

Comment: Hey guys, Im the original developer, I will work on the mentioned bug!

Comment: @Hailwood I just read your comment. Thanks for the follow up :)